# Local C* algebras - definitions (plural)

Tags: definition, operator-algebras

I am a bit worried about the equivalence of the definition of local C* algebra in Blackadar (the K-theory book, in terms of functional calculus using functions holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the spectrum) and other definitions involving subalgebras. In particular I am concerned about whether Blackadar's definition allows taking a square root of a positive operator which may not be invertible!

Any light on where to find a discussion of these matters would be much appreciated!

Comment: If nothing else, taking square roots of positive but non-invertible elements is too much to ask for, as is shown by an example like $f := (x \mapsto \sin^2(x)) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: That is a good comment - nice example!